# How do you do query a postgres database using python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a postgres database and I am doing queries in python. Right now I am just doing

```
cur.execute("""
                        SELECT 
                            "pop_total"
                        FROM 
                            "chicago_data"
                        WHERE 
                            st_contains(chicago_data.geom, ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(%(lat)s %(lon)s)', 4326), 4326)) = true
                    """, {"lat": latitude, "lon": longitude})
```

What I want to know if there is a better way to integrate my SQL and my python programming or is this the standard way it is done?

Answer (score 0):

There are many so called Object-Relational Mappers (ORMs) that can be used for a much nicer querying (or just general usage of SQL databases).

To name a few popular ones:

1. [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)
2. [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/)

But you can find plenty of others.

The good point about the ORMs is that they do not require a knowledge of intricacies of particular database. Once you learn how to use the ORM you can switch the "backend" databases easily.